# x64dbg assembly instruction changes are not present after restarting debuggee in debugger

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering

I have the Sep 14 2020 20:15:12 release of x64dbg and Windows 8.1.

I am new to using a debugger, and maybe this is a simple fix, but if I press space and change an assembly instruction and then restart with CTRL+F2, the change I made no longer appears in the code.

If I make a patch and then execute that patched executable inside or outside the debugger, the change is incorporated into the patched file, but I can't get the change to 'take' inside the debugger prior to the patch.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: That's what I'd expect - when you restart the program, it's reloaded into memory from the binary, so that all the program's data is as it should be at startup, and this would naturally replace the code as well.  I would look instead for some way to have your patch command automatically repeated when the program starts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to restart with incorporating the changes, if, say, on startup the program only runs past a given instruction once ever?

Comment: I don't know about x64dbg specifically.  But many debuggers have "hooks" to automatically perform certain actions when certain things happen.  That's what I'd suggest looking for.

Comment: Thank you! The more I look at it, the more it's starting to make sense.